# Exporting a worksheet as CSV with a Form Controls button fails

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that I export each sheet as a CSV file from. I would like to have it work with a button and it gives an error when I try that.

I have the export working

```
Public Sub SaveWorksheetsAsCsv()
    Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim SaveToDirectory As String
    Dim CurrentWorkbook As String
    Dim CurrentFormat As Long

    CurrentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    CurrentFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
    ' Store current details for the workbook

    SaveToDirectory = "D:\tmp\"

    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        WS.SaveAs SaveToDirectory & WS.Name, xlCSV
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    ' Temporarily turn alerts off to prevent the user being prompted
    '  about overwriting the original file.
End Sub
```

When I run the Macro normally, it works (exports all sheets as individual csv files and return to the original workbook.)

When I run the Macro for an **ActiveX** button (placed on a sheet), it works.

However, when I run it from a **Form Controls** button (placed on a sheet). it fails, with  this error:

> Run-time error '1004'
>   Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed

and the debugger points to this line:

```
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=CurrentWorkbook, FileFormat:=CurrentFormat
```

So, I just want to know why it fails from a Form Controls button.

Comment: Original file is not read only, and it does work if I run it manually exactly like it should, just not if I run it from a button.

Comment: OK, repo'd now, when run from a `Forms Controls` button (no idea wht though).  But it _does_ work from a `ActiveX` button.  Maybe you could switch to one of those?

Comment: I don't know why it did not occur to me to try an ActiveX control, confirmed it does work for me as well, I will just use that, thank you!