# Button (form control) runs Macro incorrectly

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro to export several tabs of a spreadsheet to csv files, then reopen the original document.  Normally the macro runs correctly, however when run through a button it fails to find other sheets in the workbook.

The document contains 5 tabs: 1 for the button, and 4 for the data (hardcoded below).  When I run the macro, it exports the 4 sheets correctly but when I press the button, **it exports the first sheet 4 times** (the one containing the button, not listed in the macro).  All I can think is that the button is failing to pass the active workbook to the macro, and therefore it cannot "see" the Worksheets object...is there something I can do to fix this?

Note that all lines other than the SaveAs commands are (theoretically) unrelated.  I have tried replacing "Worksheets" with "ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets" and gotten the same result.

```
Sub SaveAsCSVs()

Dim fullname As String
fullname = ThisWorkbook.fullname

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Ships").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\ships", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Worksheets("Weapons").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\weapons", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Worksheets("Specials").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\specials", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Worksheets("Modifiers").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\modifiers", FileFormat:=xlCSV
Application.Workbooks.Open (fullname)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Workbooks("modifiers.csv").Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you add a break point and step through it?

Comment: Interesting! If I use your code with a form button I have the same issue like you. All the exported files contain the first sheet. If I use a ActiveX button it works and the exported files contain the data I expect. One fix I found for the form button is to add an `Activate` before the `SaveAs` line. But that is not really nice. Same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57762802/exporting-a-worksheet-as-csv-with-a-form-controls-button-fails).

Comment: When I add a break point, it follows the same behavior: if I used the macro from the menu then it works normally, but if I use the button it creates a blank file based on the first sheet.

It does look like this'll just be a curiosity, since I can solve the problem with an ActiveX button.  How exactly did you add the Activate command, Storax?

Comment: Just a `Worksheets("Ships").Activate` before `Worksheets("Ships").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Ships", FileFormat:=xlCSV`,  a `Worksheets("Weapons").Activate` before `Worksheets("Weapons").SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Weapons", FileFormat:=xlCSV` and so on.

Comment: And if a place the form button on the second sheet I will always get the data from the second sheet in the exported files. No idea what's wrong here.

Comment: Oh, gross.  I'll stick to the ActiveX button.  Funny enough though, the ActiveX button always asks whether you want to save the file it closes, unless I add "Savechanges:=False".  ...which means that the regular macro process has False as the default value but the ActiveX version does not.  The lack of standard implementation is kinda terrifying.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, behavior, indeed...

Being a single sheet to be saved, please use the next adapted code. It should work in both cases:

```
Sub SaveAsCSVs()
 Dim fullname As String
 fullname = ThisWorkbook.fullname

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets("Ships").Copy 'it creates a new workbook containing only the copied sheet...
   ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ships", FileFormat:=xlCSV
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Worksheets("Weapons").Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\weapons", FileFormat:=xlCSV
  ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Worksheets("Specials").Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\specials", FileFormat:=xlCSV
  ActiveWorkbook.Close False
Worksheets("Modifiers").Copy
  ActiveWorkbook.saveas FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\modifiers", FileFormat:=xlCSV
  ActiveWorkbook.Close False
'Application.Workbooks.Open (fullname) 'no need to open, it remained opened...
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the information!  However the difficulty here isn't the export itself, it's the optimization.  The sheets are several thousand lines long and reference each other with many formulae, so copying them sequentially can take over a minute compared to 3 seconds using my code above.  The official method simply isn't optimal for my fringe case.